# How to get offset of an item relative to Scrollviewer in WPF?

Tags: c#, offset, scrollviewer

I have ListBox with multiple items and I want to get offset of an item relative to Scrollviewer.
I tried to do it, using TranslatePoint or TransformToAncestor methods, but it worked only for the items that are already visible. So how I can get an offset for the items that are in the end of list and not visible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible since you are using default ItemsPanel that is VirtualizingStackPanel. Invisible items are not attached to the visual tree, they were never measured and never arranged, so they have no position.

If virtualization is not a requirement, you should change ItemsPanel to StackPanel. This panel attaches all items to visual tree, and TranslatePoint/TransfromToAncestor will work properly.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    ...
</ListBox>
```